# Parameters of a punctured code.

Tags: coding-theory

I have the following problem I am struggling to solve.

Let $C$ be a binary $[n,k,d]$ code and let $\mathbf{c}$ be a minimum weight codeword of $C$. Let $\overline{C}$ be the punctured code obtained by $C$, puncturing on the positions $i$ where $c_i \neq 0$. I have to find the dimension of $\overline{C}$ and prove that its minimum distance is at least $\lceil \frac{d}{2} \rceil$. I am struggling with this exercise, and in general with finding the parameters of punctured code. Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you at least tell us what you found to be the length of the punctured code?

Comment: we are eliminating w(c)=d bits, so n-d. Anyway I think I figured the first part out reasoning with linear combinations

Comment: Please add what you _have_ figured out to the question instead of leaving it in the comments. You can edit the question statement by clicking on the `Edit` button below your question.